# How to know you have a good understanding of a topic in particular in maths/physic

Tags: quantum-mechanics

How do you get to a point where you know you have a good understanding of topic

Comment: when you can correctly do all the homework problems in the textbook.

Comment: When you can explain it in your own words

Comment: When you could convince someone who doesn't believe in the results that the results are correct, with a very solid argument

Comment: These are all good criteria. The reality is that almost every student doesn't understand the theory at that level. But they are goals to aspire to, which can be compromised to some extent in practice depending on your circumstances (how much time you have and whether you have good enough learning material/teachers)

Comment: I think that excellent problem solving ability alone is certainly a necessary condition for good understanding, but not a proof that one actually fully understands the topic, as there are other elements of understanding besides this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you have identified what the undemonstrated assumptions of the theory are and can demonstrate entirely by yourself some important conclusions from those assumptions.

To validate this - get a standard text book on the topic and go through the harder exercises. If you can not only complete them but explain your approach to someone else - then it is plausible that you have a practical understanding of the topic.

If at any point you shy away from an exercise, for whatever excuse your brain comes up with, that is a good indication that there is something there that you don't understand. If you cannot explain what you did, then ditto.

Reading through a book and nodding and saying - yes I understand that - is not a good indication, unless you can also say what is going to be on the next page before you turn it. It is very easy to fool yourself into thinking that you understand something just because your brain gives you the warm fuzzies about it.

Real understanding comes with the ability to solve problems in the area.

Comment: Ponder Stibbons, I'll add a bit to your last statement.  You can demonstrate real understanding when you are confident and can work a problem that has a unique combination of concepts that you haven't seen before, but for which you follow those concepts and associated math to wherever they lead, and you arrive at the correct answer.

Comment: David White - cool with that.